# How to copy a solution of a PySCIPOpt model to another model?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, scip

Given a `pyscipopt.Model` and its `Solution`, how to pass it to another model as a primal heuristic?

I'm currently writing the solution to a file via `writeSol()`, and then calling `readSolFile()` and `addSol()`. There should probably be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a bit on the structure of your two models. If they have the same variables in the same order (which is likely from what you wrote), then you can simply create a new solution in your model and copy all the values, ie:

```
variables = othermodel.getVars()
newvariables = model.getVars()
nvars = othermodel.getNVars()

newsol = self.model.createSol(self)

for i in range(nvars):
   newsol[newvariables[i]] = othermodel.getSolVal(oldsol, variables[i])

self.model.trySol(newsol)
```

Let me know if this work/ doens't work

Comment: Thank you! 
I actually want to retrieve the solution as a return value of a function. But I can actually just transform a solution into a list with .getSolVal(), and return the list.

Comment: Hi! What if variables are not in the same order? or the second problem has an initial solution form with variables from one problem and parameters?